# How I can setup dns settings in my Gentoo linux box? nslookup already do it

Tags: dns, gentoo

I can't resolve dns requests for most of programs in my Gentoo machine. I have local network at my work. It contain two dns services for local machine names and one tmg gateway for internet access.

I can't resolve dns names which must be processed by service of our internet provider.

Here is my /etc/conf.d/net configuration:

```
dns_domain_lo="local"
config_eth0="dhcp"
routes_eth0=(
  "default gw 131.107.1.20" # gateway of my local network
)
dns_servers_eth0=(
  "195.20.194.2"            # internet provider dns server
)
```

After I run `/etc/init.d/net.eth0 restart` `/etc/resolv.conf` doesn't contain specified dns server. Only two local servers which were accepted from local dhcp service.

But I cat get appropriate ip address with `nslookup www.google.com` and successful open it with internet browser.

Where I make mistake?

Comment: What about this one: `dhcp_eth0="nodns"` ?

Comment: Did you mean to specify dns name server in resolv.conf permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll do..

```
dns_domain_lo="local"
config_eth0="dhcp"
dhcp_eth0="nodns"
routes_eth0=(
  "default gw 131.107.1.20" # gateway of my local network
)
dns_servers_eth0=(
  "195.20.194.2"            # internet provider dns server
)
```

Answer (score -3):

Any distro:

`echo nameserver 10.3.0.1 > /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Gentoo regenerate `/etc/resolv.conf` in every `/etc/init.d/net.* start` so this will not work.

Comment: If you put dhcp_eth0="nodns" in your /etc/conf.d/net it won't regenerate resolv.conf.

Comment: @proofit404 Yes it will. Don't trust me? **man resolv.conf**. Apart from the /etc/init.d/net.lo script's capabilities of setting DNS you could override anything it does by a simple "/etc/init.d/afternet service" that loads after net.* and runs that command.